# How to use 2 different connection strings in a single project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio

We have a scenario where we have two SQL Server databases, one for testing and one for deployment. When I came onto the project, they had been using typed datasets and passing the connection string to determine which database. There was only one typed dataset for both.

Now, I am trying to do this with Entity Framework. While I could have two EDMX models in the same Class Library, the catch is both databases have the same tables, therefore generate the same C# classes with the same names and there is collisions.

Is there anyway to deal with this scenario?

Comment: What's wrong with changing the reference in the web.config?

Comment: But it generates a connection string with metadata from the model that I am using. Can I just switch what it points to?

Comment: I don't have a web.config. I have an App.config for the class library that the model is in.

Comment: So, how do I differentiate? If I have a connection string RREM_GilbaneEntities3 for the Prod database, what do I do? Creare a RREM_GilbaneEntities3Debug and point it to the debug database or just switch the database or the first connection string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you do is setup your `webconfig` file to point to your production DB server when you set it to release or publish it.

If you  are debugging it then it will point to your development SQL server.

It is very easy to set up, the `webconfig` file contains `web.Release.config` and `web.Debug.config`, this is where you set it to replace the connection string.

---

```
  <!--
    In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of 
    "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator 
    finds an atrribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB" 
        connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  -->
```

In your case you will put the replace attribute.

Comment: This is the best practices way to do it!  No reason to have both contexts in a single instance.

Comment: But I have a connection string from the model that is of the form <add name="RREM_GilbaneEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RREMDataAccess.GilbaneRREMProd.csdl|res://*/RREMDataAccess.GilbaneRREMProd.ssdl|res://*/RREMDataAccess.GilbaneRREMProd.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data server;initial catalog=SRP_Gilbane;persist security info=True;user id=;password=MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: @user2471435 it works the same way EDMX file use connection strings also

Comment: I don't have web config files though. I have a class library for the EF model

Comment: @user2471435 you took this connection string from somewhere, you can do it in your DLL project

Answer (score 0):

You can take the overloaded version of [Objectcontext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739017%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from which your model is derived that takes connection string as parameter

Answer (score 0):

for me the following was sufficient regarding using a gitlab ci which holds the name runner within it.

```
public static string GetConnectionString(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            if (Environment.MachineName.Contains("runner"))
            {
                return configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabasePipeline");
            }
            return configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseLocal");
        }
```